# Calculate the change in price by matching symbol in two tables and calculate the price difference at set interval

Tags: mysql

> I have two tables, as showing below. Both tables have symbol column.
>   assetList table have lastPriceUSD and VWAPUSD table have vwapUSD along
>   with the createdAt column.
>
> VWAPUSD table gets updated every 10mins and store prices of each
>   asset. I want to match the symbol in both table and then calculate the
>   price difference at 24h/7d/30d interval.

**assetList Table**

```
+----+--------------+--------+-----------------+------------------------+
| id | name         | symbol | lastPriceUSD    | circulatingSupply      |
+----+--------------+--------+-----------------+------------------------+
|  1 | Bitcoin      | BTC    | 7293.2028511419 |    17688625.0000000000 |
|  2 | Ethereum     | ETH    |  234.9522240344 |   105978867.0616000000 |
|  3 | XRP          | XRP    |    0.3711016204 | 42004966728.0000000000 |
|  4 | Bitcoin Cash | BCHABC |  359.6217859183 |    17770489.6469232500 |
|  5 | Litecoin     | LTC    |   86.7230191550 |    61699595.7334713500 |
+----+--------------+--------+-----------------+------------------------+
```

**VWAPUSD Table**

```
+--------+--------+----------------+---------------------+
| vwapId | symbol | vwapUSD        | createdAt           |
+--------+--------+----------------+---------------------+
|      2 | ETH    | 184.2507663730 | 2019-05-12 23:36:11 |
|      3 | LTC    |  84.8173610151 | 2019-05-12 23:36:11 |
|      4 | BNB    |  20.5221663735 | 2019-05-12 23:36:11 |
|      5 | NEO    |   9.1588715813 | 2019-05-12 23:36:11 |
|      6 | QTUM   |   2.3849431039 | 2019-05-12 23:36:11 |
+--------+--------+----------------+---------------------+
```

> **This is what I am trying**

```
SELECT al.symbol,
       al.lastPriceUSD,
       al.circulatingSupply,
       vw.symbol,
       vw.vwapUSD,
       100 * (al.lastPriceUSD - vw.vwapUSD) / al.lastPriceUSD as difference
FROM assetList al JOIN VWAPUSD vw
ON al.symbol = vw.symbol
WHERE al.symbol = vw.symbol AND
      vw.createdAt >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY (al.circulatingSupply * al.lastPriceUSD) DESC
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry changed it actual data.

Comment: `symbol - symbol` is always true

Comment: @Strawberry typo, I fixed it. but it shows multiple values of the same symbol. i need to calculate the change in the last 24h for each asset.

Comment: Perhaps see first comment again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *scalar subquery*:

```
SELECT al.symbol
     , al.lastPriceUSD
     , al.circulatingSupply
     , ( SELECT 100 * (al.lastPriceUSD - vw.vwapUSD) / al.lastPriceUSD
           FROM VWAPUSD vw
           WHERE vw.symbol = al.symbol
             AND vw.createdAt >= now() -interval 1 day 
             AND vw.createdAt <  now() -interval 1 day + interval 10 minute
       ) diff24h
     , ( SELECT 100 * (al.lastPriceUSD - vw.vwapUSD) / al.lastPriceUSD
           FROM VWAPUSD vw
           WHERE vw.symbol = al.symbol
             AND vw.createdAt >= now() -interval 7 day 
             AND vw.createdAt <  now() -interval 7 day + interval 10 minute
       ) diff7d  
  FROM assetList al 
  ORDER BY (al.circulatingSupply * al.lastPriceUSD) DESC
```